# A subset of an universe is the universe of a substructure if and only if tis closed under terms

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, model-theory

Let $N$ be a nonempty subset of the universe $M$ of a $L$-structure $\mathcal{M}$.

Show: $N$ is the universe of a substructure $\mathcal{N}$ if and only if it is closed under $t^\mathcal{M}$ for all $L$-terms $t=t(x_1, \cdots , x_n)$

Attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$

Suppose $N$ is the universe of a substructure $\mathcal{N}$. Then by definition we have

i) $c^{\mathcal{N}}=c^{\mathcal{M}}$ for all constants $c \in L^{\mathcal{N}}$.

ii)$f^{\mathcal{M}} \restriction_{\mathcal{N}^n}= f^{\mathcal{N}}$.

Since every constant symbol is and function symbol is a $L$-term, then by i) ii) we are done.

$(\Leftarrow)$

Suppose $N$ is closed under $t^\mathcal{M}$ for all $L$-terms $t=t(x_1, \cdots , x_n)$. Then  i) ii) hold?

I'm not sure how to expand the proof from i) ii). More specifically, I don't really under stand it means to be"closed under $t^\mathcal{M}$ for all $L$-terms $t=t(x_1, \cdots , x_n)$".

Any ideas or hints will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The terminology: to be "closed under $t^\mathcal{M}$" means that if $a_1,\ldots a_{n}\in N$ then $t^\mathcal{M}(a_1,\ldots a_n)\in N$.